# Any way to debug tasks and microtasks?

Tags: javascript

Disclaimer: tasks and microtasks are still quite blurry to me.

I'm running into some issue and I think timing is to blame.

I'm maintaining a project that uses a lot of `setTimeout(... , 0)`.

Is it possible to peer into browser's event loop and see what tasks are in the task's and microtask's queue?

I could try to use chrome's devtools timeline or slap some `debugger` keywords but it is quite tedious.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/

Answer (score 2):

*I could try to use chrome's devtools timeline or slap some `debugger` keywords but it is quite tedious*

Well, there are no shortcuts. You need breakpoints, browser developer tools and a lot of patience.

You could also make an attempt at visualizing the javascript runtime code using [the loupe tool](http://latentflip.com/loupe). This is the source code if you want to play around or extend it: https://github.com/latentflip/loupe

This project is still at the beginning and there's no way to guarantee it'll reach maturity, so best would be to dig into [developer tool documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#call-stack) and make use of it, as tedious as it might be